# Phase transition in counting feasible solutions to knapsack problems?

Tags: counting-complexity, phase-transition

Imagine that you have a normalized knapsack constraint with $n$ items and weights
$w_1,...,w_n$ satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i = 1$. I'm trying to understand the behavior of the function

$$Z(c) = \#| S \subset \{1,...,n\} : \sum_{i \in S} w_i \leq c|.$$

Clearly if $c = 0$, then $Z(c) = 0$, and if $c = 1$ then $Z(c) = 2^n$. Are there any results on phase transition behavior for $Z(c)$ when the $w_i$ are drawn randomly?

I'm aware there are results, for example, for counting the number of solutions to constraint satisfiability problems, but I haven't seen similar results for a counting the feasible solutions to a knpasack constraint.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a reference for you, just a minor remark that is too large for a comment.

We assume $w$ is chosen as follows.  Choose r.v. $x\in[0,1]^n$ uniformly at random (i.e., each $x_i$ is i.i.d. uniformly in $[0,1]$), then set $w_i = x_i/X$, where $X=\sum_j x_j$.  Then with high probability, almost all sets $S$ will have $\sum_{i\in S} w_i \sim 1/2$:

**Lemma 1.** *Let r.v. $w$ be chosen as above.  With probability $1-e^{-n/6}$, for all $\epsilon\in[0,1]$, among the subsets $S\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}$, the fraction satisfying $$\textstyle\Big|1/2 - \sum_{i\in S} w_i\Big| \ge \epsilon$$ is at most $2 e^{-n\epsilon^2/4}$.*

*Proof.* For any $x$, and $X=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ as described above,
note that $E[X] = n/2$, so by a standard Chernoff bound the probability of the event $X\le n/4$ is at most $e^{-n^2/6}$.
So, with probability at least $1-e^{-n^2/6}$, $X\ge n/4$.

Now fix any $x$ and $w$ with $X\ge n/4$, and fix $\epsilon>0$.  To complete the proof we bound the fraction of subsets $S$ such that $|1/2 - \sum_{i\in S} w_i| \ge \epsilon$.

This fraction equals the probability that $|1/2 - \sum_{i\in S} w_i| \ge \epsilon$ for a random subset $S\subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Because $w=x/X$, the condition $|1/2 - \sum_{i\in S} w_i| \ge \epsilon$
is equivalent to $|X/2 - \sum_{i\in S} x_i| \ge \epsilon X$.

Note that $E_S[\sum_{i \in S} x_i] = X/2$,
so by a standard Chernoff bound
$$\Pr_S\big[|X/2 - \textstyle\sum_{i\in S} x_i| \ge \epsilon X\big] \le 2\exp(-X\epsilon^2) \le 2\exp(-n\epsilon^2/4).$$
(The last step uses $X\ge n/4$.) $~~\Box$

We don't have to choose $w$ randomly to get the bound.
Any $w$ with $\max_i w_i = O(1/n)\sum_i w_i$ will do.

Note that the result implies a sharp threshold in the following sense:
for any $c > 1/2$, almost all sets $S$ will satisfy the given knapsack inequality $\sum_{i\in S} x_i \le c$.
For any $c < 1/2$, almost none will.